# Passing variables to Docker Desktop for Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I am new to **Docker**, and I am trying to start an image while passing some environmental variables to it through the [Docket Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop) application. I understand that one could (and probably should) use a YML file for docker-composer, or even add the "-e" flag to a CLI command. Yet, I am wondering whether what I'm trying to do is **also** possible: i.e. just pull an image from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) and fire it up in Docker Desktop while passing environmental variables.

Comment: Don't use the UI for that -- it's really non-standard and weird. Get onto the CLI instead, you'll get further, faster.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the image downloaded from docker hub as a base image to create your personnel and custom image like that:

```sh
FROM image_from_docker_hub
ENV key1=value1 \ key2=value2
....
....
....
```

And with this method you can add what you want .